# How to return a result as a column value if a row exists or not?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables table1 and table2.

```
table1 - tID,title,description

table2 - sID,tID,title,description
```

table1(t1) always contains values.
In table2 (t2), if there is a row present, the tID (Foreign key) will always match a tID in t1(primary key).

I want to create a select statement where I select all columns from t1, and create an additional column "ex" with a true or false value, depending on whether there is a record in t2, where tID matches...

```
Select t1.*, (some code) as ex from table1 t1,table2 t2;
```

Understand ? For example if `Select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.tID = t2.tID` returned any rows, ex similarly should be true... how do I do that ?

EDIT: No column can be null

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I want the select statement to match only where sID = someIdValue that I specify....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` (outer join) and then check for the existence of `tID` in `table2` by using of the `IS NULL` expression

```
Select t1.*, t2.tid is not null as ex 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.tid = t2.tid
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0ecc8861a350124759954cd7e56c15e3)

**EDIT:** "What if I wanted only the values where sID matches some value ?"

```
Select t1.*, t2.tid is not null as ex 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.tid = t2.tid and t2.sid = <some_value>
```

Comment: I don't understand - if the value is null, how do i convert it to true false ? Also, none of my columns can store null anyway - they all have to have values.

Comment: @KaizerSozay NULLs are a product of the outer join. The expression `t2.tid is null` returns true if the `tid` exists in `table2` and false otherwise.

Comment: What if I wanted only the values where sID matches some value ?

Comment: @KaizerSozay the logic was swapped (it was showing false if there entry), it is corrected now.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to match the sID ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select *, coalesce(tID = true, false) = true as is_exists from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 using (tid)
```

Comment: In the event that tID have different names in each table, how would I modify your statement ? It isn't immediately apparent.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with postgresql... the error just underlines the false keyword

Comment: @KaizerSozay you're right, mess up types in coalesce, edited

Comment: Any idea how to match the sID  as well ?

Comment: @KaizerSozay What do you mean by different names in each table? Different column names?

Comment: @KaizerSozay try to join by on clause: `left join table2 t2 on t1.tid = t2.tid and ...`

Comment: well instead of tid in both tables, lets say the column was named tid in table 1 and called t2id in table 2...

Comment: @KaizerSozay `left join table2 t2 on t1.t1id = t2.t2id`

Answer (score 1):

Try below one if this work for you.

```
 declare @T1 as Table 
(
tId int,
title varchar(25),
description varchar(50)
)

declare @T2 as Table 
(
sid int,
tId int,
title varchar(25),
description varchar(50)
)
insert into @t1 (tId,title,description) values(1,'abc','test')
insert into @t1 (tId,title,description) values(2,'abc','test')
insert into @t1 (tId,title,description) values(3,'abc','test')
insert into @t1 (tId,title,description) values(4,'abc','test')
insert into @t1 (tId,title,description) values(5,'abc','test')

insert into @t2 (tId,title,description) values(10,'abc','test')
insert into @t2 (tId,title,description) values(2,'abc','test')
insert into @t2 (tId,title,description) values(3,'abc','test')
insert into @t2 (tId,title,description) values(14,'abc','test')
insert into @t2 (tId,title,description) values(5,'abc','test')

Select distinct t1.*, 
   case when t2.tid is null then 'False' else 'True' end as ex from @T1 t1    
   left join @T2 t2 
   on t1.tId = t2.tId
```

Output

```
1   abc test    False
2   abc test    True
3   abc test    True
4   abc test    False
5   abc test    True
```

Comment: `declare @T1 as Table..` is not valid syntax in postgres SQL

Comment: those tables are just for the example but the logic is same

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS(subquery)` yields a boolean value which you can use directly:

---

```
SELECT t1.*
        , EXISTS(SELECT13 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.tID = t1.tID) AS does_exist
FROM table1 t1
        ;
```

---

- This will produce *all* the rows from t1, plus a flag indicating that one or more corresponding rows exist in t2.
- If you *only* want the t1 records that have matching rows in t2, move the `exists()` to the where clause:

---

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT13 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.tID = t1.tID) 
        ;
```